# Прошу помощи с инпутом у VueJs

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

Проблема в том, что я вывел список на страницу и добавил инпут, чтобы менять имя юзера, но что-то не так и меняет только последний инпут, и далее все инпуты меняются только по последнему, прошу вашей помощи.

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Fetch data",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      original: [],
      newArr: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUsers()
  },
  methods: {
    async getUsers() {
      const response = await fetch(this.url)
      const data = await response.json()
      this.original.push(...data)
      // console.log(data);
    },
    changeItemName(item) {
      item.name = this.$refs.value
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#container")
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <ul v-for="(item, idx) in original" :key="item.id">
    <li> {{ item.name }} {{ item.id }}
      <input type="text" @keyup.enter="changeItemName(item)">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: где код не рабочий покажи, я вивожу на страницу просто список, с инпутом и хочу когда пишу в инпут другой текст он подставлялся вместо того что там есть, тоесть вместо имени, так понятно?

Comment: кину ссилку https://jsfiddle.net/t85eakwc/2/

Comment: откуда ты взял `this.$refs.value`? Почему решил, что там будет значение инпута?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В input пробрось $event `<input type="text" @keyup.enter="changeItemName(item, $event)">` А в самой функции `changeItemName` получай значение так

```
changeItemName(item, e) {
  item.name = e.target.value
}
```

Comment: я б хотел попросить у вас чтоб обяснили что такое $event в инпуте

Comment: Это оригинальное событие DOM event:KeyboardEvent. Такой как element.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {})

Vue позволяет обращаться к нему через $event, как раз в таких случаях, когда нам надо передать и аргументы и событие в метод.

Comment: Спасибо помогли